# Oracle FN_STRING_SPLITTER "ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, plsql, ssrs-2008

I have been assigned to create an Oracle stored procedure for an SSRS report.
I came up with the following code in order to retrieve the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                     b.branch_name,
                     cu.unit_name,
                     c.CLAIM_DESC,
                     dp.legal_name,
                     c.claim_number,
                     c.date_of_loss,
                     FN_FORMAT_NAME(s.first_name, s.last_name, s.middle_name) AS staff_name,
                     c.state,
                     c.county,
                     cc.first_modified,
                     dp.policy_search_nbr,
                     c.city,
                     col.cause_name,
        CASE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                   WHEN ',' THEN SUBSTR (cp.business_name, 1, 78)
                   ELSE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
               END
        AS claimant_name,
        cp.cms_party
        FROM claimant_coverage cc
        JOIN claim c ON cc.claim=c.claim
        JOIN DEC_POLICY dp  ON dp.dec_policy=c.dec_policy
        LEFT JOIN cms_party cp ON cc.claimant=cp.claimant
        LEFT JOIN cms_col_adjuster cca ON cca.claimant=cc.claimant
        AND cca.cause_of_loss=cc.cause_of_loss AND cca.coverage = cc.coverage
        LEFT JOIN staff s ON cca.staff=s.staff
        LEFT JOIN branch b  ON b.branch= s.branch
        LEFT JOIN cms_unit cu  ON b.branch= cu.branch
        LEFT JOIN cause_of_loss col ON cc.cause_of_loss=col.cause_of_loss
        --The code below is somewhat convoluted due to a lack of LIKE IN statement in pl/sql
        --Basically, the code filters for results that fulfill the LIKE criteria for any items in the list
        JOIN (
          SELECT (branch_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE) branch_name
          FROM (
            TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Claim Service Center,Home Office,Northern Region,Property Claims Branch,Property Claim Service Center,Southern Region',','))
          ) branch_search_term
        ) branch_search_filter
            ON b.branch_name like  ('%' || branch_search_filter.branch_name || '%')
        JOIN (
          SELECT ( unit_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE ) unit_name
          FROM (
            TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Auto Subrogation,Border Entry,CSC,Casualty,Home Office,Intake,Litigation,Med Pay,Multi-line,PCSC,Primary Auto,Property,Property Subrogation,Split,Subrogation,Support,TCR,Total Loss',','))
          ) unit_search_term
        ) unit_search_filter
            ON  cu.unit_name like ('%' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || '%') OR b.branch_name like ('%(' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || ')%')
        WHERE
          cc.status IN ('Open','Reopen')
          AND (( TRUNC(sysdate - cc.status_date) >= 90 ))

UNION SELECT DISTINCT
                             b.branch_name,
                             cu.unit_name,
                             c.CLAIM_DESC,
                             cmp.legal_name,
                             c.claim_number,
                             c.date_of_loss,
                             FN_FORMAT_NAME(s.first_name, s.last_name, s.middle_name) AS staff_name,
                             c.state,
                             c.county,
                             cc.first_modified,
                             cmp.policy_search_nbr,
                             c.city,
                             col.cause_name,
        CASE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                   WHEN ',' THEN SUBSTR (cp.business_name, 1, 78)
                   ELSE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
               END
        AS claimant_name,
        cp.cms_party
        FROM claimant_coverage cc
        JOIN claim c ON cc.claim=c.claim
        JOIN cms_claim_policy ccp on ccp.claim = c.claim
        JOIN cms_policy cmp on cmp.cms_policy = ccp.cms_policy
        LEFT JOIN cms_party cp ON cc.claimant=cp.claimant
        LEFT JOIN cms_col_adjuster cca ON cca.claimant=cc.claimant
        AND cca.cause_of_loss=cc.cause_of_loss AND cca.coverage = cc.coverage
        LEFT JOIN staff s ON cca.staff=s.staff
        LEFT JOIN branch b  ON b.branch= s.branch
        LEFT JOIN cms_unit cu  ON b.branch= cu.branch
        LEFT JOIN cause_of_loss col ON cc.cause_of_loss=col.cause_of_loss
        JOIN (
          SELECT (branch_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE) branch_name
          FROM (
            TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Claim Service Center,Home Office,Northern Region,Property Claims Branch,Property Claim Service Center,Southern Region',','))
          ) branch_search_term
        ) branch_search_filter
            ON b.branch_name like  ('%' || branch_search_filter.branch_name || '%')
        JOIN (
          SELECT ( unit_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE ) unit_name
          FROM (
            TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Auto Subrogation,Border Entry,CSC,Casualty,Home Office,Intake,Litigation,Med Pay,Multi-line,PCSC,Primary Auto,Property,Property Subrogation,Split,Subrogation,Support,TCR,Total Loss',','))
          ) unit_search_term
        ) unit_search_filter
            ON  cu.unit_name like ('%' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || '%') OR b.branch_name like ('%(' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || ')%')
        WHERE
          cc.status IN ('Open','Reopen')
          AND (( TRUNC(sysdate - cc.status_date) >= 90 ));
```

When I run this code in an SQL Worksheet on the Development database, it works as expected and without error. 
[Results from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX4YT.png)
However, when I package the code inside a stored procedure and run it,
the stored procedure doesn't return any data and instead outputs the following error message:

```
<html><font color=red>ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at "CIGADMIN.FN_STRING_SPLITTER", line 16
</font></html>
```

For testing purposes, I wrote the stored procedure like so:

(PG_REPORTS.sps):

```
/*
 Procedure Name      : SP_GET_CLAIMANT_INACTIVE
 Version             : 1.0
 Description         : Returns a list of claims that have been inactive for 90 days (by default).
                       Used for CMS Inactivity Report
 Owner               : Joseph Faulkner
 Input               : p_days_inactive,p_branch_list,p_unit_list
 Output              : v_claimant_inactive_cur
 Date                : 11/21/2016
 LastModified        :
*/

    PROCEDURE SP_GET_CLAIMANT_INACTIVE
    (
    p_days_inactive               IN NUMBER := 90,
    p_branch_list                 IN VARCHAR,
    p_unit_list                   IN VARCHAR,
    v_claimant_inactive_cur       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    );
```

(PG_REPORTS.sql):

```
    PROCEDURE SP_GET_CLAIMANT_INACTIVE
    (
    p_days_inactive               IN NUMBER := 90,
    p_branch_list                 IN VARCHAR,
    p_unit_list                   IN VARCHAR,
    v_claimant_inactive_cur       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN v_claimant_inactive_cur FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
                         b.branch_name,
                         cu.unit_name,
                         c.CLAIM_DESC,
                         dp.legal_name,
                         c.claim_number,
                         c.date_of_loss,
                         FN_FORMAT_NAME(s.first_name, s.last_name, s.middle_name) AS staff_name,
                         c.state,
                         c.county,
                         cc.first_modified,
                         dp.policy_search_nbr,
                         c.city,
                         col.cause_name,
            CASE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                       WHEN ',' THEN SUBSTR (cp.business_name, 1, 78)
                       ELSE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                   END
            AS claimant_name,
            cp.cms_party
            FROM claimant_coverage cc
            JOIN claim c ON cc.claim=c.claim
            JOIN DEC_POLICY dp  ON dp.dec_policy=c.dec_policy
            LEFT JOIN cms_party cp ON cc.claimant=cp.claimant
            LEFT JOIN cms_col_adjuster cca ON cca.claimant=cc.claimant
            AND cca.cause_of_loss=cc.cause_of_loss AND cca.coverage = cc.coverage
            LEFT JOIN staff s ON cca.staff=s.staff
            LEFT JOIN branch b  ON b.branch= s.branch
            LEFT JOIN cms_unit cu  ON b.branch= cu.branch
            LEFT JOIN cause_of_loss col ON cc.cause_of_loss=col.cause_of_loss
            JOIN (
              SELECT (branch_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE) branch_name
              FROM (
                TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Claim Service Center,Home Office,Northern Region,Property Claims Branch,Property Claim Service Center,Southern Region',','))
              ) branch_search_term
            ) branch_search_filter
                ON b.branch_name like  ('%' || branch_search_filter.branch_name || '%')
            JOIN (
              SELECT ( unit_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE ) unit_name
              FROM (
                TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Auto Subrogation,Border Entry,CSC,Casualty,Home Office,Intake,Litigation,Med Pay,Multi-line,PCSC,Primary Auto,Property,Property Subrogation,Split,Subrogation,Support,TCR,Total Loss',','))
              ) unit_search_term
            ) unit_search_filter
                ON  cu.unit_name like ('%' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || '%') OR b.branch_name like ('%(' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || ')%')
            WHERE
              cc.status IN ('Open','Reopen')
              AND (( TRUNC(sysdate - cc.status_date) >= 90 ))

    UNION SELECT DISTINCT
                                 b.branch_name,
                                 cu.unit_name,
                                 c.CLAIM_DESC,
                                 cmp.legal_name,
                                 c.claim_number,
                                 c.date_of_loss,
                                 FN_FORMAT_NAME(s.first_name, s.last_name, s.middle_name) AS staff_name,
                                 c.state,
                                 c.county,
                                 cc.first_modified,
                                 cmp.policy_search_nbr,
                                 c.city,
                                 col.cause_name,
            CASE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                       WHEN ',' THEN SUBSTR (cp.business_name, 1, 78)
                       ELSE trim(SUBSTR (cp.last_name || ', ' || cp.first_name, 1, 78))
                   END
            AS claimant_name,
            cp.cms_party
            FROM claimant_coverage cc
            JOIN claim c ON cc.claim=c.claim
            JOIN cms_claim_policy ccp on ccp.claim = c.claim
            JOIN cms_policy cmp on cmp.cms_policy = ccp.cms_policy
            LEFT JOIN cms_party cp ON cc.claimant=cp.claimant
            LEFT JOIN cms_col_adjuster cca ON cca.claimant=cc.claimant
            AND cca.cause_of_loss=cc.cause_of_loss AND cca.coverage = cc.coverage
            LEFT JOIN staff s ON cca.staff=s.staff
            LEFT JOIN branch b  ON b.branch= s.branch
            LEFT JOIN cms_unit cu  ON b.branch= cu.branch
            LEFT JOIN cause_of_loss col ON cc.cause_of_loss=col.cause_of_loss
            JOIN (
              SELECT (branch_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE) branch_name
              FROM (
                TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Claim Service Center,Home Office,Northern Region,Property Claims Branch,Property Claim Service Center,Southern Region',','))
              ) branch_search_term
            ) branch_search_filter
                ON b.branch_name like  ('%' || branch_search_filter.branch_name || '%')
            JOIN (
              SELECT ( unit_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE ) unit_name
              FROM (
                TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Auto Subrogation,Border Entry,CSC,Casualty,Home Office,Intake,Litigation,Med Pay,Multi-line,PCSC,Primary Auto,Property,Property Subrogation,Split,Subrogation,Support,TCR,Total Loss',','))
              ) unit_search_term
            ) unit_search_filter
                ON  cu.unit_name like ('%' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || '%') OR b.branch_name like ('%(' || unit_search_filter.unit_name || ')%')
            WHERE
              cc.status IN ('Open','Reopen')
              AND (( TRUNC(sysdate - cc.status_date) >= 90 ));
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Error In SP_GET_CLAIMANT_INACTIVE. ' || sqlerrm);
    END SP_GET_CLAIMANT_INACTIVE;
```

[Error Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9Vf.png)

I have searched online to see what could be causing this problem and have come up empty handed.
Again, I can get this code to work in an SQL Worksheet, I just can't get it to work in a stored procedure.

I should probably explain why I implemented the following code the way I did:

```
JOIN (
          SELECT (branch_search_term.COLUMN_VALUE) branch_name
          FROM (
            TABLE(FN_STRING_SPLITTER('Claim Service Center,Home Office,Northern Region,Property Claims Branch,Property Claim Service Center,Southern Region',','))
          ) branch_search_term
        ) branch_search_filter
            ON b.branch_name like  ('%' || branch_search_filter.branch_name || '%')
```

Basically, this is my attempt at trying to implement a 'LIKE IN' statement which does not have a native implementation in Oracle. There are several instances in the database where the branch name does not exactly match the items in the list.

Comment: The error is being thrown in the custom `fn_string_splitter` function which you aren't showing.  When you're getting the error, you (or something else) has enabled `dbms_output` (`set serveroutput on` in `SQL*Plus`) and specified a buffer size of 20,000 bytes (`set serveroutput on size 20000` in `SQL*Plus`).  Your code is trying to print out more than that (I would guess because the string splitter is called many times as a result of running this query) until it exceeds the size of the buffer.  You could disable `dbms_output`, increase the buffer size, or reduce the verbosity of your output.

Comment: I'm surprised https://www.google.com/search?q=ORU-10027 didn't return anything helpful.